# Can I force a specific element to shrink in a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

While trying to comply with my company's design specification, I've run up against a bit of an issue using LinearLayout's in Android.  Overall, the general goal is to have buttons on the left and right of the screen and some text in the center.  I was able to get this working fairly easily:
[image]

The complication comes in when the screen is not large enough to accommodate all of the text.  The design specification dictates that the entire time should always be displayed, while the message text should be truncated.  To get this to work, I've created two controls (one for the message and one for the time).  I set the message control to wrap it's content expecting the wrapping to force the content to hide itself if it's oversized, but the end result I'm getting is a little different from what I'd expect:

[image: Faulty Layout]

I need to get it to the point where the "AM" in the time is displayed and the text get's abbreviated to something like: "Appointment D..." so that it all fits in the space allowed.

Here is the layout I'm using that causing issues:

```html
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/backandlistnavigation_header_phone"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/header_shade">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_backNav"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
            android:background="@color/transparent" />
        <Space
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/transparent">
            <include
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                layout="@layout/TopTextViewPhone" />
            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                layout="@layout/TopTextClockPhone" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_up"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevronup"
            android:background="@color/transparent" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_down"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_chevrondown"
            android:background="@color/transparent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction to get this issue resolved, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe think about using a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Really long text that I want to truncate. So, more text here" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="11:18 AM" />

</RelativeLayout>
```